# Will a14mm DC barrel fit in a socket prepared for 9mm?

Tags: power-supply, dc, plug

I've got a device that has a DC socket, but I think it might be for 9mm long barrels and I've already ordered 14mm jacks. Will it fit? If yes, then do I need to somehow secure the part of barrel which will stick out?

EDIT: Barrel size 2.5/5.5 mm

Comment: Wait and see or, in case it doesn't fit properly, order some shorter ones.

Comment: The jack is supposed to have a electrical contact spring midway to hold it in halfway through so it should secure itself as long as it can reach that far. Whether the contacts make it far enough is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it will work fine. The longer plug will simply stick out of the connector. You do not need to add clips since the barrel is friction locked by the ground spring inside the connector but you need to take in account the extra leverage.

In short: it will be easier to break the connector if you hit the plug. Other than than, no problems.